How to make HTML table with very many columns scroll horizontally
I have this unique problem with html tables.
What I hope to achieve:

a table within a container surrounded by padding but scrollable horizontally and vertically

What I have done

created a table that is vertically scrollable, with frozen row headings.

What problems I am facing

inability to pad the table container on the right
the horizontal scrolling is displayed but doesn't work
part of the content of the table is hidden.

techonologies

html
talwind

URL to code pen with code

https://codepen.io/davidshare/pen/poXPxQW

        <main class="flex-1 p-4 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="bg-[#1D1D1F] shadow sm:rounded-lg h-full">
                <div class="overflow-x-auto h-full">
                    <div class="overflow-y-auto h-full">
                        <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                            <!-- Table header -->
                            <thead class="bg-[#1D1D1F] sticky top-0 z-10">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 1</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 2</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 3</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 4</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 5</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 6</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 7</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 8</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 1</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 2</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 3</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 4</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 5</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 6</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 7</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 8</th>
                                    <!-- Add more headings as needed -->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <!-- Table body -->
                            <tbody class="bg-[#1D1D1F] divide-y divide-gray-200">
                                <!-- Loop through your table data here -->                        
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>                       
                                
                                <!-- Repeat rows as needed -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>


If you want table horizontal or vertical scroll you just need to add this property 'overflow-auto' to this place 

Hey your issue can be resolved by adding overflow-auto to the div just below <!-- Main content -->.Small suggestion streamline your code bit more because current code doesn't look that flexible to work with.
Below is working example.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="h-screen flex overflow-hidden bg-black text-gray-100">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside class="bg-[#1D1D1F] w-64 flex-shrink-0 h-full hidden md:flex md:flex-col fixed">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <img src="./logo.svg" alt="lorem logo" class="w-10 bg-white p-2 rounded-md"/>
          <h2 class="font-bold ml-2 text-xl">Dashboard</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grow p-4 overflow-y-auto">
            <!-- Sidebar content here -->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="py-2"><a href="#" class="text-white">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="py-2"><a href="#" class="text-white">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="py-2"><a href="#" class="text-white">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                    <!-- Add more menu items here -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="flex-1 overflow-auto flex flex-col md:ml-64">
        
        <!-- Header section -->
        <header class="border border-[#363638] bg-[#1D1D1F] p-3">
          <p>Home > Dashboard</p>
          <div class="flex justify-between p-3">
            <p class="text-4xl">Dashboard</p>
            <div class="flex justify-center items center">
              <span><img src="./alert.svg" class="w-6" /></span>
              <span><img src="./message.svg" class="w-6" /></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="flex gap-2">
            <li>page 1</li>
            <li>page 2</li>
            <li>page 3</li>
            <li>page 4</li>
          </ul>
        </header>

        <!-- Content section -->
        <main class="flex-1 p-4 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="bg-[#1D1D1F] shadow sm:rounded-lg h-full">
                <div class="overflow-x-auto h-full">
                    <div class="overflow-y-auto h-full">
                        <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                            <!-- Table header -->
                            <thead class="bg-[#1D1D1F] sticky top-0 z-10">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 1</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 2</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 3</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 4</th>
                                    
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 6</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 7</th>
                                    <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">Heading 8</th>
                                    <!-- Add more headings as needed -->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <!-- Table body -->
                            <tbody class="bg-[#1D1D1F] divide-y divide-gray-200">
                                <!-- Loop through your table data here -->                        
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">1</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">John Doe</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">john.doe@example.com</td>
                                  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- Repeat rows as needed -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

    </div>

</body>
</html>




Thank you. I did just that. This was just a dummy I created to work on my problem. My original code is broken into components.
I figured the parent container of the table must have a clear width and height for this to work. The height must be less than the content, that will force the horizontal scroll to wor,.
Thank you.

So I fixed this with a couple of actions:

Set a specific width and height to the parent container of the element you want to scroll. Make sure it is smaller than the content. This will force the horizontal scroll to appear. Do not use relative width and height.
set the overflow to auto in the parent container.

